# CreateUserAndAccount and db.SaveChanges causes duplicate user entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. The following code causes that the user will be created two times in the UserProfile Table.

```
...
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, Password);


var UserProfile = (from UserProf in _db.Users
                   where UserProf.UserName == UserName
                   select UserProf).FirstOrDefault();

UserCustomAttribute = new UserCustomAttribute();
UserCustomAttribute.UserProfile = UserProfile;
UserCustomAttribute.Name = "BelongsToAccountId";
UserCustomAttribute.Value = model.AgentModel.AccountId;

using (db = new xDb())
{
    db.UserCustomAttributes.Add(UserCustomAttribute);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
...
```

Using VS2012 debugging feature, I discovered that one entry is created when calling

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, Password);
```

And, the duplicate is created when calling

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

This is weird. I would expect that `SaveChanges()` is called in `CreateUserAndAccount(...)`?!
So, how to add something to database without duplicating created user?

Comment: Logically `db.SaveChanges()` should not be able to add another record because `CreateUserAndAccount` method is not called in the context of your `DbContext` class `xDB`. When save changes is called , all the entities in Context class with modified state will only be saved. It will help if you can provide all the code prior to the SaveChanges and details about UserCustomAttributes model.

Comment: is this your code copied? It looks like it shoudln't even compile on using (db = new xDb()). What is function you are calling it from? Is it maybe seed method?

Comment: Edited my post. The Problem is, that the dbcontext creates a new UserProfile when adding UserCustomAttribute. My aim here was to create a one to n relationship. One UserProfile has many UserCustomAttributes.